# VB.NET 3dline usercontrol that anchors left and right to parent

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a usercontrol which is a 3D line that sits above the "Ok" and "Cancel" button as seen in the Thunderbird windows sometimes:

http://s11.postimage.org/gh45ux9wj/thunderbird1.png

I do not want to have to set the anchor property manually each time I put the usercontrol on a form, that is why I wanted to make it so within the usercontrol that it docks automatically to the parent (Left=0, Width=Parent.Width).

However, I do not really manage to do so.

My attemps were manyfold, so I am not sure what I should post here.

My assumption was that I should use

```
Private Sub UserControl1_ParentChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.ParentChanged

    Me.SetBounds(0, Me.Top, Me.Parent.Width, 0, BoundsSpecified.X Or BoundsSpecified.Y Or BoundsSpecified.Width)

End Sub
```

But that does not work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an event handler to the parent's `Resize` event so that you will be notified every time the parent's size changes.  For instance, something like this will work:

```
Public Class ThreeDLine
    Private _lastParent As Control

    Private Sub Parent_Resize(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        resizeToParentWidth()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Divider_ParentChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.ParentChanged
        If _lastParent IsNot Nothing Then
            RemoveHandler _lastParent.Resize, AddressOf Parent_Resize
        End If
        _lastParent = Parent
        If Parent IsNot Nothing Then
            AddHandler Parent.Resize, AddressOf Parent_Resize
            resizeToParentWidth()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub resizeToParentWidth()
        If Parent IsNot Nothing Then
            Me.Left = 0
            Me.Width = Parent.ClientSize.Width
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Btw, is that underscore naming the new "m_"? I have always been using something like m_MyPrivateVar for private variables. Where did you get the underscore naming convention from? Is that common in C#?

Comment: No problem.  Glad to help.  Yes, it's just a naming convention to indicate that it's a private field.  It's not necessary.  Some people use 'm' or 'm_' and some just use the underscore by itself.  I used to work somewhere that required us to use the underscore, so I got used to it and it stuck :)  Last I knew there was no "official" naming convention for private fields from Microsoft, but I could be wrong.  I think it may be more common in C#, but I always thought that was silly because in C# it's case sensitive, so you can know it's private by it being lower case so the prefix is unnecessary.